# SSH Bash script for easy connection

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script which I wrote that lists out some servers/user names. I chose a # which then connects me to said server with said user name. So far the script works fine other then the fact that when I launch ssh, the bash script hangs. It doesn't dump me into ssh.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `clear`
SERVER1="1.) Server1/username1"
SERVER2="2.) Server1/username2"
echo -e "Please choose a server:"
echo $SERVER1
echo $SERVER2
read server
if [ $server -eq 1 ]; then
        serverconnect="ssh -t username1@server1.com"
        servername="server1.com"
        serveruser="username1"
else

        if [ $server -eq 2 ]; then
                serverconnect="ssh -t username2@server1.com"
                servername="server1.com"
                serveruser="username2"
        fi
fi

echo "Connecting you to: $servername as $serveruser"
echo `$serverconnect`
```

Comment: You might want to make use of a `select` around a `case`, especially if you have more than two servers (and you can use arrays to store your server names and user names). You can eliminate "serverconnect" and just do `ssh -t "$serveruser@$servername"`

Comment: In reality I have around 15 servers. Not sure about using select and case, coming to bash from a php background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just execute ssh normally. Don't put it inside variable

```
if [ $server -eq 1 ]; then
        serverconnect="username1@server1.com"
        servername="server1.com"
        serveruser="username1"
else

        if [ $server -eq 2 ]; then
                serverconnect="username2@server1.com"
                servername="server1.com"
                serveruser="username2"
        fi
fi

ssh -t "$serverconnect"
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a much easier script to connect to ssh. You can add as many servers as you want to array.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `clear`
SERVERS=('server1' 'server2' 'server3' 'server4')

echo "Server to connect:"
for server in ${!SERVERS[*]}
do
    printf "%4d: %s\n" $server ${SERVERS[$server]}
done

read -p "Select a server to connect: " CHOISE
read -p "Enter username: " USERNAME


ssh $USERNAME@${SERVERS[$CHOISE]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `clear`
SERVERS=('server1' 'server2' 'server3' 'server4')

echo "Server to connect:"
for server in ${!SERVERS[*]}
do
    printf "%4d: %s\n" $server ${SERVERS[$server]}
done

read -p "Select a server to connect: " CHOISE
read -p "Enter username: " USERNAME


ssh $USERNAME@${SERVERS[$CHOISE]}
```